# How to click a list item with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, bots, puppeteer

I'm new to puppeteer and I'm  trying to click on a selector from a dropdown menu  [the MR element here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2I5K.png)

I've tried using `await page.click('.mat-option ng-star-inserted mat-active');`

and also

`await page.select('#mat-option-0');`

here is my code, would anyone be able to help me fix this issue and understand how to resolve it in the future? I'm not to sure what methods to be using with each elelement, I think it's every time I introduce a class with spaces in the name could that be the issue?

and does anyone have any best practices for when codings things like this?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.game.co.uk/en/-2640058?cm_sp=NintendoFormatHub-_-Accessories-_-espot-_-PikaCase');
  await console.log('Users navigated to site :)');
  await page.waitFor(2300);
  await page.click('.cookiePolicy_inner--actions');
  await page.waitFor(1000);
  await page.click('.addToBasket');
  await page.waitFor(1300);
  await page.click('.secure-checkout');
  await page.waitFor(2350);
  await page.click('.cta-large');
  await page.waitFor(1200);
  await page.goto('https://checkout.game.co.uk/contact');
  await page.waitFor(500);
  await page.click('.mat-form-field-infix');
  await page.waitForSelector('.ng-tns-c17-1 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transformPanel mat-select-panel mat-primary');
  await page.click('.mat-option ng-star-inserted mat-active');
  

  
})();
```

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. It doesn't make sense. You seem to be asking whether Puppeteer is clicking something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with the script, let's see them:

- you are using `waitFor()` with a number of miliseconds, this is brittle because you never know if perhaps some action will take longer, and if it does not, you will waste time; you can substitute these waits with `waitForSelector()`; in fact, if you use VSCode (and perhaps other IDEs), it will notify you that this method is deprecated, don't ignore these warnings:

[image]

- when I use DevTools, no element is returned for `.mat-option ng-star-inserted mat-active` selector, but I can find the desired element with `#mat-option-0` selector, or I can use the longer version, but have to use a dot (`.`) before each class and delete spaces between them like so `.mat-option.ng-star-inserted.mat-active`, you can see a CSS reference [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), the point is that with spaces, it looks for descendants, which is not what you want

These two changes should give you what you need, this is a result when running on my side, you can see that `Mr.` has been selected:

[image]

I got there with this script:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.game.co.uk/en/-2640058?cm_sp=NintendoFormatHub-_-Accessories-_-espot-_-PikaCase');
  await console.log('Users navigated to site :)');
  await page.waitForSelector('.cookiePolicy_inner--actions');
  await page.click('.cookiePolicy_inner--actions');
  await page.waitForSelector('.addToBasket');
  await page.click('.addToBasket');
  await page.waitForSelector('.secure-checkout');
  await page.click('.secure-checkout');
  await page.waitForSelector('.cta-large');
  await page.click('.cta-large');
  await page.goto('https://checkout.game.co.uk/contact');
  await page.waitForSelector('.mat-form-field-infix');
  await page.click('.mat-form-field-infix');
  await page.waitForSelector('#mat-option-0');
  await page.click('#mat-option-0');
})();
```

However, this is still not ideal because:

- you handle the cookie bar with clicks, try to find a way without clicking; perhaps injecting a cookie that disables the cookie bar (if possible)
- the code is one big piece that is perhaps ok for now and this example but might become unmaintainable if you keep adding lines to it; try to reuse code in functions and methods

Comment: Thank you so much @pavelsaman this is great using waitForSelector(); is there possablity of adding a delay to this? Thank you for the Css refrence aswell great help. and to simplify the code would you have any examples of how to intergare functions lets say i add await page."function or varliable name"(); I think this would work but it does not would you have any suggetions?? Thank you so much for helping me :)

Comment: I don't know examctly what you mean by delay, Playwright will repeatedly query for the selector; if it finds it, it will continue executing the script, if it doesn't find it, it will eventually time out. You can change the timeout, more on that in the [docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-selector). In other words, no `waitFor()` with number of seconds should be in your script.

Comment: Thank you, I have recently made a new post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69773155/how-to-use-input-forms-within-iframes-with-puppeteer)  and have updated and made change's to the code and you have helped me get to this point, I really appreciate it, do you think you could have a look and help me out with the last bit? Thank you